# Override a global variable defined in <script> tags using a userscript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am trying to make a Tampermonkey userscript that needs to override a global variable that is defined in a small script in a `<script>` element in the HTML. This variable controls another, bigger script.

It seems that when the page loads, the global variable is first defined from the script in the HTML for a quick moment before the userscript defines it, and the big script loads after the HTML script but before the userscript. I need to have the big script load after the variable is defined to my desired value by my userscript, or it won't work.

Comment: https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
I tried using Greasemonkey instead, and it worked perfectly.